# Not being able to call the right data

Tags: java, object, filereader

I've been at this for hours and I kinda frustrated. I would love a helping hand if someone would please have a look at my code and tell me why I can't use Student1 in StudentRecWithinput.Update();

It works without it in there but it seems to only use the last line of data that i am reading in.

MAIN

```
package Database;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice1 = "";

    System.out
            .println("Would you like to update a students GPA? Please Input Yes or NO.");
    choice1 = Keyboard.next();

    if (choice1.charAt(0) == 'y' || choice1.charAt(0) == 'Y') {
        recupdate();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Alright, Goodbye!");
    }
}

public static void recupdate() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice2;
    System.out.println("Here are the records!\n");

    StudentRec Student1 = new StudentRec();
    StudentRec Student2 = new StudentRec();
    StudentRec Student3 = new StudentRec();

    System.out
            .println("Who's gpa will you be edditing? Please input (1, 2 or 3)");

    choice2 = Keyboard.nextInt();
    if (choice2 == 1) {

        StudentRecWithInput.update(Student1);

    }

    if (choice2 == 2) {
        StudentRecWithInput.update(Student2);
    }

    if (choice2 == 3) {
        StudentRecWithInput.update(Student3);

    }
}
}
```

STUDENTREC

```
package Database;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentRec {
// student related//

private String lastname;
private String firstname;
private String major;
private int age;
private static double gpa;
private static int credit;

// /non student related////
File info = new File("studentinfo.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(info);
static int count = 0;

public StudentRec() throws FileNotFoundException {

    {
        count++;

        if (count == 2) {
            scan.nextLine();

        }

        else if (count == 3) {
            scan.nextLine();
            scan.nextLine();
        }

        firstname = scan.next();
        lastname = scan.next();
        age = scan.nextInt();
        setGpa(scan.nextDouble());
        major = scan.next();
        setCredit(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + " "
                + getGpa() + " " + major + " " + getCredit() + "");

    }

}

public static int getCredit() {
    return credit;
}

public void setCredit(int credit) {
    this.credit = credit;
}

public static double getGpa() {
    return gpa;
}

public void setGpa(double gpa) {
    this.gpa = gpa;
}

}
```

STUDENTRECWITHINPUT

```
package Database;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentRecWithInput extends StudentRec {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);


public StudentRecWithInput() throws FileNotFoundException {
    super();



}

public static double update(int credit, double gpa)
{
    double pastpoints = getCredit() * getGpa();
    int newcredhours = keyboard.nextInt();
    double newpoint = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double semestergpa = newpoint / newcredhours;
    double cumulate = (pastpoints + newpoint) / (newcredhours+ getCredit());

    System.out.print(pastpoints);

    return cumulate;

}

}
```

studentinfo.txt

```
Bob Bobbers 19 3.5 CPS 55 
John Johners 20 3.7 BIO 70
Kat Katters 21 3.8 ITC 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of StudentRecWithInput

```
update(int credit, double gpa)
```

expect int and double, but you are calling it with

```
StudentRecWithInput.update(Student1);
```

you need to change the signature to:

```
update(StudentRec student)
```

to be able to pass student information into the method.

You also should read more about the difference between static and non static methods, as right now your code have no changes of compiling.

Comment: Thanks! It did compile but the problem i'm actually having now is its using student 3's info even if i pick student 1. Any idea why?

Comment: This is most likely because you use
private static double gpa;
private static int credit;

static means that there is a single field for the class, not each instance. try removing static keyword

Comment: I had tried that and main is asking for it to be changed back to static when calling StudentRecWithInput.update();

Comment: then instead of getCredit() use student.getCredit(), and also remove static from before getCredit(). I will not tell you how to change every single line - try investigating

Comment: I don't know any other way to say this but thank you so much. Those few lines right there were magic. Is there anyway source you would recommend for a new learner??

Comment: I strongly recommend reading: SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Exam  310-065 (2008), that will give you all the java knowledge you need to start our journey

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to adjust your strategy.  Consider using the following steps:

1. Read your input file into a Vector of StudentRecord. (Your code tries to ready your input file each time you create a StudentRec)
2. Then ask what record should be updated
3. Then ask for update data for that record

So your main might have `Vector<StudentRec>`

While your `StudentRec` class would have an `update` method (no arguments) that you call when you need to change that `StudentRec`.

Exact details left as an exercise for questioner, since this appears to be a school task.